# Twig Best Practices: Multiple include Files or Multiple rendered Files?

Tags: php, templates, include, twig, render

I am writing a record keeping app in PHP using Twig for my templating engine. I typically make my web page header, footer, navigation, and other recurring sections ‘included' files, so as to limit the amount of code in any one file for easier editing, troubleshooting, etc. Of these "standard" includes, one or more contains dynamic content which changes depending on which page is being loaded.

So, in each php file I could render the included files ( $twigHandle->render('templateName', array()) ) along with the main file, which means several render statements per php file, or I could include files in each of my twig templates ( {% included twig file  %} ) which means several include statements per Twig template. OR, I could render the dynamic included files, and {% include  %} the static included files. Does anyone have a suggestion as to which is the best practice and why?

Comment: Create a base template with the static includes. Then add a block e.g. content and extends from your base template and overwrite the block e.g. content in the child template

Comment: Have you tried inheritance?

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks. A form of that is indeed what we ended up doing. We created a class that holds information for each page, and pass an object of that class in the render statement. Then we have static includes in the page templates so all have access to the object and information therein.